# Display a form in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I would like to show a form in prestashop module and would like to store that value in database. How is it possible?? Is there any prestashop expert ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use custom HTML block and add your form code inside that. And off course have to use a hook to show up that HTML block in the site.
There are lots of free Custom HTML block modules available.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at all the modules available in the modules/ directory.

If you want to display a form in the back and/or the front office, you'll have to override different methods of the Module class, and you'll have to use the different hooks available..

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this free module :

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/391966-megablock-16-module-gratuit/

With this one you can add HTML in some hooks from back-office. 
Everything is stored in database.
You should use Helpers and Tools class (Helpers show forms and Tools::getValues() does what it says...)

In MegaBlock there is also TinyMCE available. Have a look, this module is really useful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can develop a module by using hooks based on the hooks used the form will be displayed in that position in prestashop while using hooks you need to assign a tpl file in that tpl file you can write the codings to display a form

And also you can develop a module with a separate controller and you can assign a tpl for that controller.